# entry point (_main) undefined xcode 6

Tags: ios, xcode

I can't for the life of me find a solution to this! I'm using Swift. All of a sudden I get this error:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture i386:
  "_main", referenced from:
     implicit entry/start for main executable
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture i386
```

It doesn't matter what simulator/device I try to run for, I still get it:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_main", referenced from:
     implicit entry/start for main executable
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
```

What is this?! I've almost removed everything from my project. I.e. all frameworks and everything. It's still there.

Please help me

Comment: I accidentally removed AppDelegate from the Compile Sources under build phases

Answer (score 25):

Have this in your AppDelegate.swift:

```
import UIKit

@UIApplicationMain
```

Comment: This lead me to the answer. I hadn't included the AppDelegate to the tvOS target. Thanks!

Comment: In my case, I had commented out the `@UIApplicationMain` from my `AppDelegate` class and started using a custom `main.swift`. The problem was that I deleted the reference and didn't noticed.

Comment: Explanation about the difference between `@UIApplicationMain` and `@main`: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67429098/what-is-the-differnce-between-main-and-uiapplicationmain

Answer (score 11):

Another cause (not for you but for others searching for an answer) is that `AppDelegate.swift` is for some reason not included in the app target. I don't know why that would happen-- I assume it was user error on my part-- but without that you'll get this error, and the cause isn't obvious. Make sure the checkbox for the file is checked in the app target.

Answer (score 7):

I had the same problem, but I just forgot to put `@UIApplicationMain` on the top of the AppDelegate.swift

Answer (score 5):

My Issue was this:
 "main.m" got removed the project.

Comment: That was happen when I relocate .xcodeproj file and do the manual reorganize Compile Sources section under Build Phases

Answer (score 3):

My problem was the following. I had 2 AppDelegate files. The original one that I wanted to delete, and another one I wanted to add. I first added the new one to the project and then deleted the old one. Following this order created a linker error. It worked when I deleted the new one and added it again to the project. Cheers

Answer (score 2):

I had this same error and found that main.m was included in the list of project files, but was not ticked in the Target Membership list.

Answer (score 0):

Some of the classes and frameworks(like FB SDK) are not ticked like in the picture.
So, I manually ticked(only .m files and frameworks) in all classes and frameworks in the Project Navigator.[image]

Answer (score 0):

If this error come you have two problems:

1. you comment out (with `//`) the `appleDelegate.swift`, you should uncomment it
2. you miss the `appleDelegate.swift` in your project

Answer (score 0):

To fix this issue in Xcode 12.3, add the `@main` attribute to `AppDelegate`.