# What is the differnce between @main and @uiapplicationmain

Tags: swift, uikit

I need help understanding when to use `@main` vs `@uiapplicationmain`.

From what I know, `@uiapplicationmain` is an easier way of calling the `uiapplicationmain(:::)` where the class that is made after `@uiapplicationmain` is used as the App Delegate. I also know that it also creates an `UIApplication`.

I also know that app delegate becomes the entry point for the project.

From what I have read I was told that `@main` is also a entry point but it requires an main function.

What I want to know is what do they mean by the main entry point.  Like what is Xcode doing to make it the "entry" point. And how does the whole `@main` thing work, as in how does it differ from `@uiapplicationmain` and what is it doing to the way Xcode runs the code.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

All code has an entry point: the place where whoever calls that code actually calls. How does the *whole* program, comprising many Swift files, actually get started? We need an entry point for the *whole* program, which the runtime will call to launch us.

In Swift, this is the *main.swift* file. Its job is to call UIApplicationMain, which creates some instances including the app and the app delegate and gets the event loop running (and stays running for the rest of the time the app runs). A minimal *main.swift* file would have to look like this:

```
import UIKit
UIApplicationMain(
    CommandLine.argc, CommandLine.unsafeArgv, nil, 
        NSStringFromClass(AppDelegate.self)
)
```

However, no one ever uses a *main.swift* file! It's boilerplate, so why bother? Instead, you say `@main`, and a *main.swift* file is generated for you behind the scenes. In particular, you put the attribute `@main` on your AppDelegate class, so the *main.swift* generator knows which class to instantiate as your application delegate.

Two more things to know:

- Before Swift 5.3, `@main` was called `@UIApplicationMain` instead. From that point of view, they are identical, two names for the same thing.
- New in Swift 5.3 and Xcode 12, you can designate one of your own types as `@main` and give it a static `main` function, where you do whatever you would have done in the *main.swift* file. That is something `@UIApplicationMain` cannot do:

```
    @main
    struct MyMain {
        static func main() -> Void {
             UIApplicationMain(
                 CommandLine.argc, CommandLine.unsafeArgv, nil, NSStringFromClass(AppDelegate.self)
             )
        }
    }
```

Comment: sorry could you explain further the second pointer because it isn't clicking for me. From my understanding your saying that @main also allows you to specify a main function anywhere you want and works the same as main.swift file.

Comment: As I demonstrate at https://github.com/mattneub/Programming-iOS-Book-Examples/blob/604368f458076dd40a8f4d0676a2aa79adb8e390/bk1ch06p297main2/bk1ch06p297main/AppDelegate.swift

Answer (score 4):

[@main](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/ReferenceManual/Attributes.html#ID626) is part of the new [SwiftUI lifecycle](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/app), introduced in iOS 14.

[@uiapplicationmain](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24516329/14351818) is the older version that's part of [UISceneDelegate](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiscenedelegate) and [UIApplicationDelegate](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiapplicationdelegate), but is still in use. Both represent your app's lifecycle.